# CronJob starting from 9: 30 AM to 12: 30AM

Tags: cron

How to run a cronjob starting from 9 AM to 12AM, since cron starts from 0-23, not 23-0.

What is the proper procedure?

Comment: I believe this question is answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67158/crontab-entry-with-hour-range-going-over-midnight

Comment: No thats not my expected Answer.

Comment: What if you just use 9-23?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to use two cronjobs for that since cronjob Hour value starts from 0-23

```
// CronJob Calling From 9:30 AM to 12:30 AM

0-30 9-23 * * *
0-30 0 * * *
```